# How to generate a random orthogonal matrix with constant magnitude complex entries

Tags: matlab, matrix, orthogonal

I would like to generate a random matrix that

1. Its columns are orthogonal to each other.
2. The entries of each column are complex values with constant magnitude.

As an example the DFT matrix has orthogonal columns and all the elements have absolute value of one. How can I generate some other random matrices with the same properties?

Comment: random is okay, but you have to tell its distribution.